# Java-Eclipse Package Recommendation

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have been told that Eclipse is a good tool for programming in certain languages. Is Eclipse recommended for Java programming? If so, what is the recommended Eclipse Package to DL for Java Programming at a university student level?

Comment: Please refer below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152691/is-eclipse-the-best-ide-for-java

Comment: Please follow below link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152691/is-eclipse-the-best-ide-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2) is good for you as a starter

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse is very well suited for java programming. In fact, it is one of the two major free tools. The other one is netbeans. The eclipse universe contains a lot more than java and it has, in my opinion, a broader scope than netbeans. To start you can use

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2

which is especially for java developers.

At our university we start in the first term with another environment for learning java, with BlueJ. It has a much simpler user interface and it is better suited when you learn your first programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with "eclipse classic" (get it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)). You will also need a [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
Another nice IDE to try is [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).