# Why the is flexbuilder plugin for eclipse so slow to open and compile?

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction, time, eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder

I've got a decent computer. ( something with dual-core in the name and a lot of ram ). 
Sometime FlexBuilder prompt the "builder project" loading bar only when i open a simple mxml file. 
It's look like he does some difficult jobs... i don't ask for anything fancy. I just want the file open, in text mode.
Every time i hit ctrl+s, i fear the "building project who take forever" thing. I've disable the automatic build, but it's not convenient.

Another thing, more understandable. I'v got a Ant task who compile our code with the flexBuilderSdk. It's take forever ( like 2 min for 100 .as file and 20 .mxml file ).

For the two question : Is that normal ? Can i do something ? Because it's killing my productivity ! ( no, seriously ;-) )

Comment: Have you any previous experience where it compiled a lot faster?

Comment: Yes. All the other. ( gcc, javac ). Like i said, i can understand the compilation issues. But definitivly not the opening issue, it must exist a config for tell flexbuilder to "just open the file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anirudhsasikumar mark a point : Improvement of the Flex4 SDK have been backported. 
http://www.deitte.com/archives/2008/10/a%5Ffaster%5Fflex%5F3.htm
It's a little bit faster, but i encounter some problem with firefox then. ( Dont ask why ! ) 
The issue : The result SWF work on IE7, but not on Firefox ( unlimited waiting at the loading )

But a real improvement of the building is to use FCSH, to avoid compile the same file two time. It's improve the performance drasticly.

http://wildwinter.blogspot.com/2008/04/fcsh-wrapper-for-ant.html

Answer (score 2):

Flex compiler performance is known to be pretty slow. They are making an effort to improve compiler performance for Flex 4.  See the developer notes here:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Notes+on+Compiler+Performance+Improvements

Compiling a Flex application is a 2-step process. First, the MXML files are compiled into the equivalent ActionScript classes. If you add the "-keep" compiler parameter, you'll be able to see all these files in a folder called "generated."  After the AS3 classes are created, then the AS compiler turns these into bytecode in the form of a .SWF file.

If you have a slow hard disk (say a 5400 RPM laptop drive) that will also affect the performance of compilation.  I would definitely recommend disabling "Build Automatically" and just press CTRL-B when you want to build.  It's not very difficult to do that when you want to build, much better than waiting for a compile every time you change a file.

Answer (score 2):

The above mentioned improvements have also been backported to the Flex 3 SDK by Brian Deitte. You can try this out at [his blog](http://www.deitte.com/archives/2008/10/a_faster_flex_3.htm). It is way faster.

Comment: The compilation was taking 2min, now it's 1min50sec .... not very convincing. But indeed, it's faster.

Comment: The improvement affects re-compilation the most. First time, there won't be much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are some tweaks you can do with the Flex Builder Configuration

More here:
[Link](http://weblog.mrinalwadhwa.com/2008/06/18/flex-builder-performance-tweak/)

Comment: This tweaks is well know for eclipse user. It increase the amount of ram that FB is allowed to use. Not helpfull for me, the value is already to 2 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Use the settings in [[How can I reduce Eclipse Ganymede's memory use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94331/eclipse-memory-use][1]) and read the article calderas sent.