# Eclipse Memory usuage in Windows Vs Linux

Tags: windows, linux, eclipse, memory-management

Can someone please give me the details about the Eclipse memory usage in Windows XP and Linux? 
I heard Eclipse consumes less memory in Linux compared to Windows? 
Is it true? What ever the OS is, IDE will look for some amount memory so how will it vary with OS?

> **Related Question:**
>
> [Eclipse memory use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94331/eclipse-memory-use)

Answer (score 1):

eclipse.ini sets the size of the Java JVM used by Eclipse. So, you can actually set the memory parameters accordingly depending on how much physical memory your machine/OS has available:
e.g.
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
**--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M**
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
**-Xms40m
-Xmx512m**

Answer (score 0):

I found Eclipse to run well on XP and Windows 7, barely cutting into my memory (3GB on XP, 6GB on the Win7 machine). It also runs really well on my Macbook 13" OSX Snow Leopard with 4GB of ram.

A guy at work runs Ubuntu, he says he has no real problems with it other than it can chokes during big SVN commits, which I have experienced on all the machines I used it on.