# Eclipse memory leakage

Tags: eclipse, memory-leaks

I'm using eclipse neon. Whenever i'm opening eclipse, it's showing `out of memory problem occurred` and it is asking me to close the eclipse. 
(While seeing task manager in my PC. eclipse taking more percentage of CPU. )
Do I need to change anything in eclipse settings. ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out of memory error in eclipse.why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816234/out-of-memory-error-in-eclipse-why)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with large projects that are indexing a lot of php files. Eclipse might be using your system default JVM memory allocation.

You can try override this either by editing the eclipse.ini file and changing the memory allocation there or by running eclipse using additional arguments:

eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xmx256M

where you change the 256 to a larger number as necessary. My current value is 1024