# My eclipse IDE keeps crashing becasue of out of memory

Tags: android, eclipse, out-of-memory

my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

trying to increase vmargs to 1024m caused other errors like Permgen space errors.

what is wrong?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743992/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have a very old version of Eclipse. I would firstly suggest updating to see if it resolves the problem.

If you really don't want to update, I suggest specifying a larger Permgen space by adding the following line into `eclipse.ini`:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

I then strongly recommend using at least 768 MB heap size, preferably 1024 MB:

```
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start eclipse with follow paramenters:

```
eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

see below link:-

[How can I reduce Eclipse Ganymede's memory use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94331/how-can-i-reduce-eclipse-ganymedes-memory-use/101995#101995)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the size of Permgen space by adding the following command to the eclipse.ini file: -XX:MaxPermSize=128M (maybe you may need to increase the size to 256M). Then you may increase the maximal memory size to 1024MB.

If you want to use more memory (more than 2 GB) you need 64bit version of JRE.